# Wrapper implementation for an abstract method in the base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class

I have a base class inherited with many subclasses. I need to define a new signature for an abstract method, which is mostly a wrapper. I tried this

```
class B {
 public:
  virtual void f() = 0;
  void f(string msg) { /* print msg and call f() */ }
};

class D : public B {
 public:
  void f() override { /* implementatation */}
};

int main() {
  D d;
  d.f("msg");
}
```

But it doesn't compile and give the following error

```
error: no matching function for call to 'D::f(string)
```

My questions are:

1. Why cannot `D::f(string)` be resolved?
2. Why does any of the following fix the problem?

   - renaming `f(string)` to `f2(string)` (ugly)
   - defining `D::f(string x) { B::f(x)}` (ugly as it has to be defined in every subclasses)
   - removing the abstract method, `B::f()` (not acceptable)

Any better solution?

Comment: The derived `f` override is hiding the base `f(std::string)`. Try placing `using B::f;` in your derived class to bring them in from `B`

Comment: @Alejandro Answers belong as answers, not as comments.

Comment: Given that one `f` calls the other `f`, they have subtly different roles. So renaming them to distinguish the higher level initiator from the implementation could be worthwhile simply for clarity (in addition to solving the problem).

Answer (score 6):

The issue is that you *hid* `B::f(std::string)` here:

```
class D : public B {
public:
  void f() override;
};
```

When you call `D.f("msg")`, name lookup will find the one `f()` in `D` and stop looking. We *first* find the candidate functions *then* perform overload resolution. Since that one happens to take no arguments, you get the compile error.

If you want to use the other overload of `f`, you need to bring it into `D` as well, like so:

```
class D : public B {
public:
  using B::f;
  void f() override;
};
```

Now we have `D::f()` (the overridden virtual function) and `D::f(std::string )` (which we brought in from `B`).

An alternative, trivial solution would be to simply rename one or the other function so you don't have this problem to begin with.

Comment: Much better than what I was going to write anyways! Great answer

Comment: Any reason why compiler stops looking for a matching function once it finds a non-matching candidate? To me it makes sense to continue the search over all candidates before reporting an error. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: @nmoses The order here is (1) find the candidate functions (2) prune to the viable candidate functions (3) pick the best viable candidate. Step (1) is just name lookup. Once we find `D::f()`, we're done with that step. Then step (2) removes it since it's not viable.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the [NVI](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Non-Virtual_Interface) idoims? Such as:

```
class B {
 public:
  virtual void f() = 0;
  void f(string msg) { 
    /* print msg and call f() */
    std::cout << msg;
    f();
  }
  virtual ~B() {}
};
```

Then you should as far as possible try to call the non-virtual member function from the base class (by reference or pointer), such as:

```
D d;
B& b = d;
b.f("msg");
```